# Use of "well" in "Britain’s Labour Party is in thrall to a man well to the left of Mr Sanders"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I have a question about a sentence from an article of The Economist Magazine:

> Britain’s Labour Party is in thrall to a man **well** to the left of Mr
>   Sanders.

Does the word "well" in this sentence mean "to a great degree or extent"*?

Below is the paragraph where I encountered this sentence.

> The United States is not the only country where the establishment is
>   on the ropes. Britain’s Labour Party is in thrall to a man well to the
>   left of Mr Sanders. In the first round of France’s recent regional
>   elections, the far-right National Front won the largest vote.
>   Populists are leading the polls in the Netherlands and running the
>   government in Poland and Hungary. In politically correct Sweden,
>   nativists are polling at 30%.

The whole article is available here: http://www.economist.com/node/21689543/print

Thanks a lot for everyone's help in advance. I really appreciate it.

---

*this is definition 3 of the adverb "well" from [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/well).

Answer (score 5):

Yes: "a man well to the left of Mr Sanders" pretty much means "a man who is to the left of Mr Sanders to a great degree or extent." "Well to the left" is a shorter way of saying this, and it sounds better. Using the adverb "well" here lets the writer avoid modifying one prepositional phrase with another; in this case, "to the left to a great extent" would even repeat the same preposition "to," which would have sounded bad.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.